# reading array json with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have this array tv, when I read this array with a loop for, it just give me the last item, in this case Toshiba,
how can I do to it show me the TV brands??

```
for (var i=0;i<tv.length;i++){
            $('#item').html(tv[i].Brand)}
<div id='item'></div>
```

Array tv:

```
var tv = [{"Name":"TV","Brand":"Samsung"},
{"Name":"TV","Brand":"Toshiba"},
{"Name":"TV","Brand":"LG"}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`html()` overwrites the content on each iteration, that's why only the last one is visible, the others are overwritten. You should be using append:

```
$('#item').empty();
for (var i=0; i<tv.length; i++){
    $('#item').append(tv[i].Brand);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

*The problem:* You have only one `div#item` element and you are updating its value in every iteration.

*Solution:* Dynamically create and append an element to show each item in the array like:

```
for (var i=0;i<tv.length;i++){
    $('<div/>').addClass('item').html(tv[i].Brand).appendTo('.container');
}
```

where:

- `item` is a class - now that you have multiple elements
- `container` - assumed to the parent element under which you want the items displayed